# How can I control the content of the HTTP HOST header in requests issued from my website?

Tags: http, jquery, http-headers, host

Is anyone familiar with a way in which I can post a link on my website, that when accessed will cause users to issue an HTTP request to a 3rd party site with custom content in the HOST header (different from the actual host/domain to which the request is sent to on the IP level)?
A short example to clarify my intention - 
a request sent to www.example.com:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: $$CUSTOM_PAYLOAD$$ (not www.example.com)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have seen several discussions here on the subject of issuing requests with CUSTOM headers, but this is not the case as the header is a legitimate header accepted by the recieving party.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

That is not how HTTP works. The `Host` header is set by the client, and matches the host name from the request-URI. You can **not** let a browser perform a request to `http://foo/` and make the host header contain `bar`:

> [**RFC 2616, section 14.23 Host**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23)

> The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port
> number of the resource being requested, as obtained from the original
> URI given by the user or referring resource (generally an HTTP URL,
> as described in section 3.2.2).

> The Host field value **MUST represent
> the naming authority of the origin server or gateway given by the
> original URL**. This allows the origin server or gateway to
> differentiate between internally-ambiguous URLs, such as the root "/"
> URL of a server for multiple host names on a single IP address.

Please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.